# Jquery mobile not updating URL properly on MVC4 RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having a problem with jquery mobile not updating the URL on an MVC4 RedirectToAction call from a controller.  I've read other similar questions that have multiple resolutions, but none have worked for me.  I want the jquery mobile loading messages to appear between pages, so I cannot use $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false as a solution.

Start URL :

```
//localhost/Application/Demo/Views/FirstPageController/
```

If I leave my code as is (below), it will show this same URL when it should be showing this URL:

```
//localhost/Application/Demo/Views/SecondPageController/Edit
```

I've tried using TempData to hold a dataurl from within the controller, but it just ends up appending the dataurl onto the above URL.

For example,

```
//localhost/Application/Demo/Views/FirstPageController/
```

will show up as

```
//localhost/Application/Demo/Views/FirstPageController/#Application/Demo/Views/SecondPageController/Edit
```

instead of

```
//localhost/Application/Demo/Views/SecondPageController/Edit
```

How do I get it to display the proper url for the next page?

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FirstPageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "SecondPageController");
    }
```

Layout.js (runs globally for all pages)

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "Loading...";
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = true;
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "b";
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "";
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (x, y) {
            showProgress();
        },
        complete: function (x, y) {
            hideProgress();
        }
    });
})

function showProgress(element) {
    if (element == undefined) {
        $("#FormSubmit").find("input").addClass("ui-disabled");
        $("#FormSubmit").find("select").addClass("ui-disabled");
        $("#FormSubmit").find("button").addClass("ui-disabled");
        $.mobile.loading('show');
    }
    else {
        $(element).addClass("ui-disabled");
        $.mobile.loading('show');
    }
}

function hideProgress(element) {
    if (element == undefined) {
        $("#FormSubmit").find("input").removeClass("ui-disabled");
        $("#FormSubmit").find("select").removeClass("ui-disabled");
        $("#FormSubmit").find("button").removeClass("ui-disabled");
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }
    else {
        $(element).removeClass("ui-disabled");
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }
}
```

Button (from the first razor page)

```
<input type="submit" data-icon="arrow-r" data-mini="true"  data-iconpos="right"    name="Continuebutton" value="Continue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your Url manually in the new page-object together with the redirect:

```
SetTempDataUrl("MyController", "MyAction", new[] { param1, param2});
RedirectToAction("MyAction", "MyController", new [] {param1, param2});
```

### jqm html

```
<div data-role="page" id="mainPage" data-theme="a" @TempData[ "DataUrl" ] >
...
</div>
```

### mvc code

```
public void SetTempDataUrl( string controller, string action = "", IEnumerable<string> param = null )
{
    List<string> content = new List<string>() { controller, action };

    if ( param != null )
    {
    content.AddRange( param );
    }

    TempData[ "DataUrl" ] = "data-url=" + Url.Content( "~" ) + string.Join( "/", content.Where( s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty( s ) ) );

}
```

### Explanation

JQM is changing pages through some internal ajax loading methods. If you are redirecting an action inside the server code jqm doesn't get notice of that and doesn't change the url correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this to our layout js:

```
function showProgress(ajax) {
    var element = $("div[data-role='page']");
    if (element != undefined) {
        var docHeight = $(element).height();
        $(element).append("<div id='overlay' class='overlay'></div>");
        $(".overlay").height(docHeight)
        $(".overlay").fadeIn();
        $.mobile.loading('show')
    }

}


function hideProgress(ajax) {    
    if (ajax) {
        $.mobile.loading('hide')
    }
    var overlay = $("div[data-role='page']").find(".overlay");
    if (overlay != undefined) {
        $(overlay).fadeOut();
    }

}

$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "Loading...";
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = true;
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "b";
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "";
});
```